# Empty result set with Folders SharePoint Online REST api with throttling

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using the folders **REST api with SharePoint Online** to return subfolders for a folder: `/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('folderServerRelativeUrl')/folders`. This works great until the number of `folders hits > 5000` and throttling kicks in. Rather than returning an error which I can present to the user, I get an empty result set with no error. I have tried everything from changing to `odata=verbose` etc. but all I get back is an empty result set in this scenario.

If I use the lists REST api I get the throttling error I would expect: `/_api/web/lists(guid'" + listid+ "')/items`

Anyone know how I can get throttling errors to be surfaced using the `/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('folderServerRelativeUrl')/folders` api call with SharePoint online?